# How do I insert two edge loops equally spaced from the edges?

Tags: modeling

I find myself doing this quite a lot in Blender 2.8: Add temporary *centered* edge loop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> click, <kbd>Esc</kbd>), then use Offset Edge Slide (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - I think this is the default?) to generate 2 *mirrored* edge loops that are equal distance from the corners of the shape, then delete the temporary center edge (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Hopefully this isn't too confusing - the point is to quickly create two edge loops that are identically spaced from the edges. This seems like an extremely useful task. My question is - Does Blender have some mechanism to do this in one step? The ability to create 2 edge loops and **edge-slide** them away from each other simultaneously?

I'm okay with using add-ons if anyone is aware of a tool that does this.

**EDIT**

After posting, I starting playing around with the loopcut_slide shortcut and may have came up with exactly what I wanted. I haven't fully tested this, so it may completely fail at something later. But so far, it seems pretty good.
It creates two edges (in one click/drag), and moves them toward/away from each other simultaneously.

[image: shortcut]

[image: cutting]

If you guys have trouble seeing the shortcut, here are the most important settings:

- Shortcut Command: **`mesh.loopcut_slide`**
- Number of cuts: **2**
- Factor: **-0.5** (this starts them in the center - use 0.0 to start at default spacing)
- Single Side: **Enabled** (this was the magic checkbox that made it work)
- Clamp: **Disabled** (otherwise, they cannot move to the center)

The only issue so far is that it is easy to accidentally slide the wrong way with clamp turned off. So it may be better to leave that on.

For anyone not familiar with creating custom shortcuts, you just go into User Preferences -> Keymap -> 3D view -> Mesh (Global) -> scroll to bottom and press *add new*, expand the new entry and type in `mesh.loopcut_slide` into the text box. Then set up the options as above.

**EDIT 2**

After playing around with this some more, it appears this setup does not work as well as I hoped. When the enclosing edges have strange angles, the cut-slide does not perform the way you would expect. So my vote goes to Lemon's suggestion of using Bevel after adding a single loop cut. It works perfectly in all cases 
except when your model has UVs (edit/correction: bevel **does** work well with UVs). I will update this if I manage to stabilize this crazy shortcut.

Comment: Using bevel (ctrl+B) on the first created edge loop? With 'percent' option

Comment: And for the second question, I use this https://www.screentogif.com/ but there are others.

Comment: You can post your edit as an answer. Haven't tested it, but it looks great.

Comment: Interesting, the *Single Slide* option doesn't appear in the *Adjust Last Operation Panel*.

Comment: I know. I thought I tried to figure this out before, and wasn't able to get it working. I don't remember seeing that setting then. I'm not sure what Single Slide means exactly, which is why I'm not sure if this will break down in some specific situation.

Comment: I'll check with the developers if it's intentionally left out or if it was simply forgotten during 2.8 development.

Comment: I've created a task, might get closed if it's considered a feature request, but we'll know why the option isn't there: https://developer.blender.org/T69218

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you get any information about what it does exactly. My guess is that it has something to do with sliding in one direction. If you cut anything other than 2 loops with that option, it has very strange behavior.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I made the mistake of calling that setting "Single Slide", but it is actually "Single Side". Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Robert, I think Bevel corrects UVs

Comment: You are correct. I didn't expect it would since it didn't have an option for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for the first loop.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it using the percent option.

[image]

Comment: ah, cool. You can press ctrl+b, 0.5, enter to make it quicker

Comment: This is probably the best built in method available

Comment: Maybe even why the _Single Slide_  option isn't available in the UI?  In the interests of keeping the interface lean?

Comment: @RobinBetts, only the devs know it.

Comment: Single-side is used to implement "Offset Edge Slide" (Ctrl-Shift-R), tested exposing this and it's not very useful to expose AFAICS.

Answer (score 3):

You can scroll the mouse wheel to increase the number of edge cuts.
[image]

Then dissolve the centre loop
[image]

Then you'll end up with
[image]

If you then want move them I guess you'd scale them on the x-axis. Not sure there's an easy way to do it if it's not along one of the local or global axes, though.

Comment: This is not good approach, because it neither solves the problem (slide is required not scale otherwise it just works with faces aligned with the axis) nor does it need less steps than loop cut with offset

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what he's asking for then. Unless you're saying that's correct except for the off-axis issue.

Comment: Yes and using a middle loop cut and then loop cut with offset is what Robert already did and this approach requires more steps. Didn't mean to sound harsh, it's just that the point of the question was to reduce the steps required.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported by "Offset Edge Slide"

- Select the face loop you want to operate on.
- Invert the selection (C-i).
- Offset Edge Slide (C-S-r)

  - Enable Even Spacing (e)